# Image scaling with linear slider

Tags: javascript, math

I have a linear slider that ranges from 0.5x to 10.0x and then an associated image that is scaled in real time.

My issue is that while the slider is linear, it results in non-linear changes to the image. A very small movement from 0.5x to 1.0x results in a 100% change in the size of the image. At the other end a change from 9.5x to 10.0x results in a 5% change.

What function can I apply to a linear scale (on the slider) that results in a linear scale on the image?

Answer (score 2):

You want to have an exponential zoom (sometimes called a Fiegenbaum zoom). [Here's an example](http://aenhancers.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=392).